# Teradata - Calculate the previous quarter date start date and end date from current date

Tags: teradata

I have current_date in Teradata which 18 DEC 2019

I have to calculate the previous quarter start date and end date from the above current_date.

```
Input               =     '2019-12-18'
Output Start Date   =     '2019-07-01' 
Output End Date     =     '2019-09-30'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a place to ask for complete code to be done for you. You need to make an attempt and we can help if you have any specific problems during that attempt

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using the `TRUNC` function, something like:

```sql
SELECT 
  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -3), 'Q') AS Start_Quarter, -- Previous quarter start
  TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'Q') - 1 AS End_Quarter -- Current quarter start date - 1 day
```

Give it a try and let me know.  This assumes the mistake in the manual is still considered a "mistake".

Also, depending on what `TD` version you're using, you may be able to use built-in functions:

```sql
SELECT 
  TD_QUARTER_BEGIN(CURRENT_DATE) AS Start_Quarter,
  TD_QUARTER_END(CURRENT_DATE) AS End_Quarter
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242552/getting-the-number-of-day-in-quarter-teradata)
[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/5rM7GF6kTb0Mvnp4CcK50g)
[Built-in functions](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/w19R4KsuHIiEqyxz0WYfgA/c8yTMUKB4u2urCqqlNcgXg)

Comment: To get the previous quarter: `Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date, -3), 'Q') AS Start_Quarter, 
Trunc(Current_Date, 'Q') - 1 AS End_Quarter`. But more important: don't use `TD_QUARTER_BEGIN` because it's based on the stupid business calendar and might not return the expected result unless you force `TD_QUARTER_BEGIN(CURRENT_DATE, 'TERADATA')`. And it will fail outside of the years 1900 to 2100 while TRUNC works for all dates.

Comment: Oops, I forgot it was for the previous quarter.  Updated.  Thanks Dieter.

Comment: Thank you very much @ravioli ,@dnoeth for your help!

Comment: Happy to help :)